# How to modify author names in biometrika.bst

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I am using `biometrika.bst` for my reference. It can be download for free from [here](http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/biomet/for_authors/). For most part, it works exactly the way I want except for author names. As shown in the picture below, the last name `CLEVELAND` is all in capital. **My question is how to modify the style file `biometrics.bst` so that I will have the normal output `Cleveland`, please? Thank you!**

[image]

Comment: Mhhh, if you want to publish in the journal you probably should not change their `.bst` file at all. And if you don't publish in their journal why would you use their `.bst`?

Comment: Find `FUNCTION {bib.name.font}
{ scaps }` in the `.bst` and replace it with `FUNCTION {bib.name.font}
{ skip$ }` in a copy of `biometrika.bst` that you have renamed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locate `biometrika.bst` on your machine, copy it to a place LaTeX can find it and rename it to, say `biometrika-nmn.bst`.

Then find the two lines reading

```
FUNCTION {bib.name.font}
{ scaps }
```

and replace them with

```
FUNCTION {bib.name.font}
{ skip$ }
```

that is, make `scaps` into `skip$`.

Then use `biometrika-nmn` instead of `biometrika` in your document.

Comment: Where can I learn this kind of syntax, please? It is not very intuitive to understand `scaps` and `skip$`. Could you explain the underlying reason or provide some background information, please?

Comment: You can read up about the `.bst` syntax in [Tame the BeaST](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf). In `biometrika.bst` the only place where `\textsc` appears is in `scaps`, then we find that there is a function `bib.name.font` that uses `scaps` and indeed `bib.name.font` is used in `format.names` to format names. If we simply define `bib.name.font` to be `skip$` it does nothing (in contrast to `scaps` which takes its argument and wraps it into `\textsc{...}` - roughly)

Comment: @LaTeXfan ^^^^^^

Comment: What does ^^^^^^ mean? Happy? Angry?

Comment: @LaTeXfan I just added that because I had forgotten to ping you in the long comment I had written and wasn't too sure whether the system would be doing that for me automatically. But then I needed some more characters in the second message because your name isn't long enough to get me over the minimum threshold, and ^^^ looks like an arrow and directs your attention to the post above, at least that is what I thought.